# Woocommerce change image based on a single attribute

Tags: plugins, php, functions

I've been searching for a while for this one.

We have an online store which will have about 1000 products. Most of them are variable products. The set up is that the rings will have different variations for quality etc. There is a 'metals' option where you can pick silver gold etc.

The metals dont generate variations as they are all the same price.

Is there a way to change the image based on the Metal attribute selected. Adding variations and then images could add over 100 variations to some products.

Comment: Welcome! The best people to help you with this question is the WooCommerce team, as they know their code best, and questions about third-party plugins are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.